# How make textboox and button left margin always same by resizing the screen

Tags: html, css, less

how make textbook and button left margin always same by resizing the screen?
 this is my css code:

```
.forgot-password-textbox {
    font-size: @textbox-font-size;
    border-radius: @textbox-border-radius;
    border: @border-lines solid @Black;
    padding: @padding-40 / 4;
    width: @forgot-password-textbox-width;
    box-shadow: 0 1px @Grey;
    margin-bottom: @forgot-password-textbox-margin-bottom;
    position:relative;
}


.forgot-password-button {
    margin-left: @forgot-password-textbox-button-margin-left;
    margin-top: auto; 
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    position:relative;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<div>
    <div>Email Address</div>
    <div><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" id="email" class="forgot-password-textbox"></div>
    <div>
        <label id="Message" class="forgot-password-error-message"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn-reset-password" onclick="resetPasswordHandler()" class="orange-button forgot-password-button">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need Email and submit button left margin stay same with all page sizes.

This is how I see the page with regular screen:
[image]

and this is when screen get smaller:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of @forgot-password-textbox-button-margin-left for the different screen sizes?

Comment: you have to use css media query to target that particular view and account for the button and textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `box-sizing: border-box;` on the input field, and then have the submit button use `margin-left: auto`. So long as both are `display: block;`, it should work.

Here is the JSBin for proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/helosub/1/edit?css,output